# Put multiple files and directories to a one file database

Tags: debian, database

I've been creating my own type of database for a while now without knowing anything basics about databases. So I ended up saving it in directories.

I recently found out that most databases uses a single file to operate, and not millions of files. Because looking through one file takes less memory to operate.

Each file contains about 6 lines of information about the "filename". It contains Title, category, popularity, etc. and no randomness. It is stored at a location looking like this:

```
database/*/*/*.txt
```

The two first stars describes the category of the file, and the bottom layer is where the files are saved.

What database application would be easy to convert and what would fit best for this solution?

Server is running Debian i3 4 GB RAM and I have a windows PC available as well.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer properly. You meantioned that each file has about 6 lines, but are the lines records, or is the file a record containing the information for itself?

Comment: the 6 lines are information about the "filename". Title, category, popularity, etc..

Comment: All files has the excact same pattern. Title, category popularity etc. So there is no kind of randomness in it.

Comment: That was one example, but you should walk throught the whole structure. What are the folders? Why are there multiple levels? You should decribe the relationship from the current layout to a traditional database (e.g. tables, records, relationships, etc.).

Comment: Updated the question. But not all database systems are the same. That's why I asked if there would be any database system that can easily be converted?

Comment: Any database system will be able to do it. The question is more, what does it have to provide in terms of accessibility, searching, etc.

Comment: I built the search engine from scratch. Coded in PHP. If search contains more than one word, it will put it to an array and check if all words contains in filename title. One word, and it will simply check if the filename contains the search. Once 40 files are echo-ed, it will stop. Click next page and it will load up results between 40 to 80 instead of 0 to 40.

Comment: Found an application called elasticsearch. So I'm creating a program in c# that will go through all files and send them together with their containing.

Comment: elasticsearch is probably overkill for this project.  Have a look at sqlite

Comment: overkill in a way that it is hard to setup and get going, or that it consumes much resources? Because I checked out how it works, and it doesn't look so complicated. I'll just code a foreach loop for all files, then send over each file's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asking for too much. It's not just a click and go. I thought more people had problems like this, but then I realized that everyone are using premade search engines.

I ended up download the whole database to my windows computer, and code a program in c# that automatically goes through all files, gets the content and POST it to an elasticsearch database which I installed on the Debian server. I should probably have created a file to file converter which I later can just put straight into the database but ended up doing a file to pure POST request.

Drawback of doing this, is that speeds are not too high and it took 2 hours to transfer 700 000 files to the database.

Program will not be released publicly because of specific strings I used in the files. So this was way harder than I expected.